# Как быстро на c# искать в строке массив строк?

Tags: массивы, c#, строки

Сейчас ищу в строке line вхождение массива строк s

```
string[] s = { "тест1","тест2","тест3","тест4" };

for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
{
  if (line.IndexOf(s[j]) > 0)
  {

  }
}
```

Как можно искать ещё быстрее этого кода?

Comment: Вам придётся вспомнить алгоритмы поиска. Вот [эти](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns), например, [алгоритм Рабина—Карпа](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm).

Comment: [А есть и на русском](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B0?wprov=sfla1)

Answer (score 1):

Если массив строк берется из какой-нибудь БД, то не проще ли сразу отбирать нужные строки из БД и не нагружать C#.
Но если так сильно хочется сделать на C#, то вот один из вариантов быстрого поиска с помощью LINQ.

```
string[] s = { "тест1", "тест2", "тест3", "тест4" };
var result = s.Where(tmp => tmp == "тест3"); // для точного поиска
var result = s.Where(tmp => tmp.IndexOf("тест") >= 0); // для подстроки
```

Comment: А чем это быстрее кода из вопроса? Тем более, что это проверяет на равенство, а не наличие подстроки.

Comment: Про базы данных ни слова у автора. Линку врятли быстрее выполнит проверку чем перебор символов за один проход.

Comment: проверять нужно строку, не базу

Comment: проверять нужно наличие подстроки

Comment: Код был приведен в качестве примера...
Я думаю, не составит труда его модифицировать, если охота искать по подстроке, то можно написать так:
var fil = s.Where(tmp => tmp.IndexOf("тест") >= 0);
В переменной fil будет результат выборки, насчет скорости не знаю, не тестировал, но даже если и будет работать одинаково, то кода меньше в разы получается.

Comment: У вас в s массив подстрок, вы ищете подстроку в массиве подстрок, а это не та задача, что нужна TC, ему нужно найти все подстроки из массива s в строке line

Answer (score 0):

Способы проверки, содержит ли `line` хоть один элемент из массива строк `s`.

```
s.Any(line.Contains)
s.Contains(line);
Array.IndexOf(s, line) >= 0
```

А это, если нужно делать что-то со строкой, которая входить в массив:

```
foreach (string str in s)
{
  if(line.Contains(str))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

можешь конвертировать массив строк в паттерн например
"тест[1-4]"
когда находишь первый подходящий символ проверяешь патерн с конца, чтоб когда паттерн не распознается сразу перескакивать на много символов вперёд.